# Determine if value in one column of data frame has more than one corresponding value in another column R

Tags: r, dataframe

Trying to do some data analysis on a data frame of example customers (EC) and looking to determine which customers are being shipped to from more than one warehouse (DC).

The end state goal is comparing the name of the EC to the DC and determining if there are EC's with more than one DC mapped to them.

```
If(EC > 1 DC) {
EC = num(DC)
}
```

Obviously the above does not return my intention and I'm not even sure this requires a loop.  Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 10
dc_id ec_id  DC                    DC_ZIP EC                                   
EC_ZIP `Zip-Zip`   Miles `Revised Rate` cost_per_mile
<chr> <chr>  <chr>                 <chr>  <chr>                                
<chr>  <chr>       <dbl>          <dbl>         <dbl>
1 DC13  M2980  ATLANTA_RDC_WAREHOUSE 30168  SAFEWAY_AUBURN_GROC_DCAuburn         
 98047  30168-98047  2587           4457          1.72
2 DC13  M29831 ATLANTA_RDC_WAREHOUSE 30168  FRED_MEYER_PV_DGRPUYALLUP            
98371  30168-98371  2592           4465          1.72
3 DC13  M2983  ATLANTA_RDC_WAREHOUSE 30168  COSTCO_WASH_WHOLESALE_AUSUMNER       
98390  30168-98390  2589           4461          1.72
4 DC13  M2983  ATLANTA_RDC_WAREHOUSE 30168  COSTCO_WASH_WHOLESALESUMNER          
98390  30168-98390  2589           4461          1.72
5 DC13  M1989  ATLANTA_RDC_WAREHOUSE 30168  WALMART_DC_7021GRANDVIEW             
98930  30168-98930  2447           4487          1.83
6 DC16  M2015  Orlando, FL           32803  
MCKESSON_MED_SURG_NORTHBNORTHBOROUGH 01532  32803-01532  1244           2254          
1.81
7 DC16  M20151 Orlando, FL           32803  CLUB_800_BJS_DISTRIBUTIOUXBRIDGE     
01569  32803-01569  1239           2246          1.81
8 DC16  M20181 Orlando, FL           32803  GERIATRIC_MEDICAL_SURGERWOBURN       
01801  32803-01801  1276           2305          1.81
9 DC16  M2018  Orlando, FL           32803  DEMOULAS_SUPER_MARKETSTEWKSBURY      
01876  32803-01876  1280           2312          1.81
10 DC16  M2020  Orlando, FL           32803  
MEDICAL_SPECIALTIES_DISTSTOUGHTON    02072  32803-02072  1269           2294          
1.81
11 DC16  M2028  Orlando, FL           32803  MARK_STEVENS_W101WOONSOCKET          
02895  32803-02895  1243           2209          1.78
```

EDIT 2:

```
DC <- as.data.frame(dc_ec_cost$DC)
EC <- as.data.frame(dc_ec_cost$EC)
EC$occurences_in_dc <- rowSums(sapply(dc, function(col) dc_ec$EC %in% col))
```

error is "x must be an array of 2D"

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: @RuiBarradas posted above, hope this helps

Comment: How are you expecting to match the customer with the shipping order? The dc_id and the ec_id look like they have different forms. As do EC and DC.  Can you describe what a match would look like?

Comment: @DanHall I was more thinkning along the lines of the dc_id vs. EC name comparison since.  So more or less: for Mark_Stevem, how many DCs match that name.  Make sense?  It would presumably be easiest by matching the DC ID to the actual EC name

Comment: I"m still confused by what you are trying to compare. The dc_id is always DC2. What is the actual EC name?  Is it the value of the EC element? You have no matches in your sample, and it doesn't look like they are of the same form.

Answer (score 0):

```
dc <- data.frame(x = sample(1:20, 10), y = sample(1:20, 10), z = sample(1:20, 10))
ec <- data.frame(w = sample(1:20, 10))
ec$occurences_in_dc <- rowSums(sapply(dc, function(col) ec$w %in% col))
```

Here we create a data frame dc, with 3 columns x, y, and z
Then we create a data frame ec, with one column, w.

Then we create a new column in ec, occurences_in_dc that represents the number of times each of ec$w occurs in a column in dc

The same thing with nonnumerical data:

```
dc <- data.frame(x = sample(letters, 10), y = sample(letters, 10), z = sample(letters, 10))
ec <- data.frame(w = sample(letters, 10))
ec$occurences_in_dc <- rowSums(sapply(dc, function(col) ec$w %in% col))
```

If you need more flexibility than a literal string exact match, you can use a different function, `grepl` with a regular expression or a fixed match.

Comment: How would I do this with non-numerical data?

Comment: "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" is the error I'm receiving when attempting your code.

Comment: i see you added your sample data. i should have waited to see what the structure was :)  in my toy sample, there are two data frames, one dc, one ec. The principles apply, but yes, here, a column is being extracted from a data frame with $

Comment: If you see my code I just added above, it looks like we're almost there.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something along these lines?

```
library(tidyverse);
as.data.frame(lst) %>%
    group_by(EC) %>%
    mutate(nDC = n()) %>%
    filter(nDC == 1);
## A tibble: 10 x 8
## Groups:   EC [10]
#   dc_id ec_id  DC                     DC_ZIP EC           EC_ZIP Zip.Zip   nDC
#   <fct> <fct>  <fct>                  <fct>  <fct>        <fct>  <fct>   <int>
# 1 DC2   M2028  ALTA_VISTA_REGIONAL_DC 24517  MARK_STEVEN… 02896  24517-…     1
# 2 DC2   M2028  ALTA_VISTA_REGIONAL_DC 24517  MARK_STEVEN… 02895  24517-…     1
# 3 DC2   M2907  ALTA_VISTA_REGIONAL_DC 24517  RALPHS_GROC… 92507  24517-…     1
# 4 DC2   M2153  ALTA_VISTA_REGIONAL_DC 24517  OK_GROCERYP… 15205  24517-…     1
# 5 DC2   M2379  ALTA_VISTA_REGIONAL_DC 24517  CVS_DISTRIB… 37774  24517-…     1
# 6 DC2   M22740 ALTA_VISTA_REGIONAL_DC 24517  HARRIS_TEET… 28079  24517-…     1
# 7 DC2   M2907  ALTA_VISTA_REGIONAL_DC 24517  RALPHS_PARA… 90723  24517-…     1
# 8 DC2   M2153  ALTA_VISTA_REGIONAL_DC 24517  HBC_SERVICE… 15301  24517-…     1
# 9 DC2   M2379  ALTA_VISTA_REGIONAL_DC 24517  CVS_DISTRIB… 37922  24517-…     1
#10 DC2   M22740 ALTA_VISTA_REGIONAL_DC 24517  HARRIS_TEET… 27410  24517-…     1
```

Explanation: Turn `list` into `data.frame`, `group_by` column `EC`, store the number of entries per `EC` in `nDC`, and `filter` rows where `nDC == 1`.

---

### Sample data

```
lst <- structure(list(dc_id = c("DC2", "DC2", "DC2", "DC2", "DC2", "DC2",
"DC2", "DC2", "DC2", "DC2"), ec_id = c("M2028", "M2028", "M2907",
"M2153", "M2379", "M22740", "M2907", "M2153", "M2379", "M22740"
), DC = c("ALTA_VISTA_REGIONAL_DC", "ALTA_VISTA_REGIONAL_DC",
"ALTA_VISTA_REGIONAL_DC", "ALTA_VISTA_REGIONAL_DC",
"ALTA_VISTA_REGIONAL_DC",
"ALTA_VISTA_REGIONAL_DC", "ALTA_VISTA_REGIONAL_DC",
"ALTA_VISTA_REGIONAL_DC",
"ALTA_VISTA_REGIONAL_DC", "ALTA_VISTA_REGIONAL_DC"), DC_ZIP = c("24517",
"24517", "24517", "24517", "24517", "24517", "24517", "24517",
"24517", "24517"), EC = c("MARK_STEVENS_MERCHANDISENORTH_SMITHFIE",
"MARK_STEVENS_W101WOONSOCKET", "RALPHS_GROCERYRIVERSIDE",
"OK_GROCERYPITTSBURGH",
"CVS_DISTRIBUTION_INCLOUDON", "HARRIS_TEETER_SUPERMARKEINDIAN_TRAIL",
"RALPHS_PARAMOUNT_DISTRIBPARAMOUNT", "HBC_SERVICE_COWASHINGTON",
"CVS_DISTRIBUTION_T101KNOXVILLE", "HARRIS_TEETER_SUPERMARKEGREENSBORO"
), EC_ZIP = c("02896", "02895", "92507", "15205", "37774", "28079",
"90723", "15301", "37922", "27410"), `Zip-Zip` = c("24517-02896",
"24517-02895", "24517-92507", "24517-15205", "24517-37774", "24517-28079",
"24517-90723", "24517-15301", "24517-37922", "24517-27410")))
```

Comment: Error: nDC not found

Comment: @Franchise Ah yes, I had changed `n` to `nDC`. Sorry, should be fixed now, please try again. Mind you, this is only a rough start; since your sample data actually contains no rows where you have multiple entries per `EC` it's difficult to provide a specific solution.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I updated my code snippet to include multiple DCs, let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(EC, DC) %>%
  count() %>% 
  filter(n > 1)
```

Here is a test where the counts are reported if `n>1`.

```
set.seed(2)
df2 <- data.frame(
  EC = sample(LETTERS[1:8], 20, replace = TRUE),
  DC = sample(letters[1:8], 20, replace = TRUE)
)

df2 %>% group_by(EC, DC) %>%
  count() %>% 
  filter(n > 1)

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
# # Groups:   EC, DC [3]
#   EC    DC        n
#   <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1 A     h         2
# 2 C     b         2
# 3 D     g         3
```